# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else'

Tags: php, wordpress, reprodutor-de-video

Estou tentando colocar um botão de próximo episodio, ele está funcionando normal, o problema é que ele aparece nos filmes, onde ele deveria só aparecer em episódios de séries. Tentei resolver o erro sozinho fazendo a class do botão retornar um valor que só apareceria se estivesse em "Episódios", caso estivesse em outro lugar ele retornaria "Array", então tentei usar o css para quando ele tiver "Array" no class ele ocultasse o botão com o display: none, mas não funcionou e deu erro: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else'

Se alguém poder ajudar eu agradeço

Obs: uso o tema Wordpress "Dooplay" versão 2.4.1

Código:

```
player.once('play', () => {


    <?php
     $postmeta = doo_postmeta_episodes($postid);
     $tmdbids  = doo_isset($postmeta,'ids');
    $temporad = doo_isset($postmeta,'temporada');
    $episode  = doo_isset($postmeta,'episodio');
     $episode_pagi = DDbmoviesHelpers::EpisodeNav($tmdbids,$temporad,$episode);
     $next_episode = doo_isset($episode_pagi,'next');
     $link_next = !empty($next_episode) ? $next_episode['permalink'].'" title="'.$next_episode['title'].'"' : 'href="#" class="nonex"';
    ?>
 

$('.jw-media').append(`<a class="<?php echo $postmeta ?>" target="_parent" href="<?php echo $link_next ?>" id="proximoep">Próximo Episódio <i class="fas fa-forward"></i></a>`);

});

    player.on('time', e => {

        let duration    = player.getDuration();
        let currentTime = Math.floor(e.position);


     if(currentTime > duration - 120){
            $('#proximoep').hasClass('Array');
            $('#proximoep').css('display', 'none');
     } else {  
            $('#proximoep').css('display', 'inline-block');
           }  else {
            $('#proximoep').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
```

Comment: O seu `if` possui dois `else`. Isso não faz muito sentido.

Comment: entendo, você sabe algum jeito de arrumar isso, ou poderia me recomendar alguma documentação sobre, serei muito grato

Answer (score 0):

O código tem os dois **else** seguidos,
sendo a condição **if** uma condição de verdadeira ou falso

Deveria ter um código com a seguinte estrutura

```
if(condição) {

   //código quando a condição é verdadeira
} else if ( condição2) {
  
  //código quando a 2 condição é verdadeira~
} else {
 
  /código quando todas as anteriores condições são falsas
}
```

Pelo que percebi da ideia do seu código, na parte final do mesmo, falta-te um **if**

uma vez que a função **hasClass** devolve um **bool**

onde o código deveria ser o seguinte

```
if(currentTime > duration - 120){
    if($('#proximoep').hasClass('Array')) {
        $('#proximoep').css('display', 'none');
    } else {  
        $('#proximoep').css('display', 'inline-block');
    }
 } else {
    $('#proximoep').css('display', 'none');
 }
```